# jquery transitions problems on bootwatch template, integrated with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, client

I have gotten a template off of https://wrapbootstrap.com/. I have been able to integrate one of their more basic templates, Blocks, into meteor. However now I am trying to integrate TWILLI Air (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0196957) a more advanced template. I am able to integrate it, the styes and such, however the jQuery slide events don't seem to be working.

In blocks the template that I got to work, I didn't need any packages except for `bootstrap-3`. I have added the same for this project which brought in the various needed styles. However with twilli I am getting a client side console error:

[image]

Which makes me think that the twilli `initialise-function.js` isn't getting linked up with the nesessary .js files/packages, therefore variables/functions are undefined.
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two errors that are showing in your console are complaining about functions that are defined in `functions.min.js`. Did you include that file?

If so, the problem is likely that `initialise_document_ready_functions` and `initialise_window_load_functions` are getting called before `functions.min.js` is loaded. If that's the case, I'd replace the document ready and window load events with Meteor startup.

**Replace this:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    initialise_document_ready_functions();
});

$(window).load(function()
{
    initialise_window_load_functions();
});
```

**with this:**

```
Meteor.startup(function()
{
    initialise_document_ready_functions();
    initialise_window_load_functions();
});
```

Disclaimer: I haven't looked at what these functions are doing and am not sure if they need to be called in a particular order.

Comment: Great! Your solution fixed the transition problems, however the errors are still present. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's still complaining that those functions are undefined? What happens when you call them manually from the console?